# IOS. Where to store user data after authorization?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, nsuserdefaults

I have REST APIManager class - singleton for working with server api.
There is login method that returns user Token entity;

All other API methods use the token to make requests.
Where should I store that token entity after login?
And how to use that token in other API methods?

Of course, I can store token in NSUserDefaults and implement methods in APIManager like this:

```
func createNews(news:NewsEntity, token:TokenEntity){
...
}
```

But I think its good idea to abstract from TokenEntity argument in methods. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Storing sensitive information in NSUserDefaults is not recommended. You should use [Keychain services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1), instead:

> By making a single call to this API, an app can store small bits of secret information on a keychain, from which the app can later retrieve the information—also with a single call. The keychain secures data by encrypting it before storing it in the file system, relieving you of the need to implement complicated encryption algorithms.

Now, the iOS Keychain provides a pretty low-level API, so it is usually better to use a higher-level wrapper, such as those provided by [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith), or [keychain-swift](https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift).

For example, using the latter, storing to and reading from the keychain is as simple as doing (after the required setup):

If you prefer, you can go the direct way and use the sample provided by Apple at the above link.

```
let keychain = KeychainSwift()
keychain.set("hello world", forKey: "my key")
keychain.get("my key")
```

EDIT:

As to code structure, you could create a class to encapsulate the token and any other information required with each request. This class would have, e.g., an `init` method taking the token; and a method called `createNews` with the following simplified signature:

```
func createNews(news:NewsEntity) {
    ...
```

Depending on your style preferences, this could be singleton reading your token from the keychain (or NSUserDefaults, although that would not be advisable).

Comment: Why user default is not recommended, keychain saves the thing for ever until OS is cleaned. But generally we use to store in user default, as that will be removed when App is removed from device. Can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks for reply, The question was not about security, it was about code organization predominantly, I asked: how to avoid token argument in all API methods requires  that token. I use rxAlamofire,Alamofire.

Comment: @Janmenjaya: basically, you want to store sensitive information using stronger encryption. anything that is not sensitive is fine with nsuserdefaults. say, if you connect your device to a mac, you can easily read an app's nsuserdefaults -- that's pretty lame a security.